# What does this enemy effect icon mean?

Tags: torchlight-2

I'm seeing a strange icon appear over enemies on a random (fairly rare) basis. The icon I'm talking about is shown on the left side of the screenshot below:

[image: Strange icon]

In this screenshot, you can see it appear over two stone pillars. When it appears over normal enemies, they appear to run away from me. None of my gear currently seems to have a unique effect (it's all pretty standard stuff), so what am I missing? Any ideas as to what this icon means?

**Update:** So I was able to recreate the icon on the practice dummy in town, but there's no associated effect icon above the enemy health bar! Here's yet another screenshot:

[image: Screenshot of strange enemy icon]

Note that the only two effect icons that show up are, in this instance, burning and my weapon's special effect (which happens to be silence, if I remember correctly). I've seen these icons outside of seeing the large yellow one above the enemy, so I don't think they are related. The mystery deepens...

Comment: What dungeon is this in? Some dungeons have unique puzzles or other things, so that might help narrow it down.

Comment: @Alex It is not area specific - I've seen that status effect before even on the training dummy, but I was not the one who cast it, so I don't remember what it was.  However, if I were to guess, that area may be Act 2 Brood Hive (or the universal guess of Mapworks).

Comment: If the effect lasts long enough, you can hover over the pillar, keep your left mouse button held down, and go hover over the corresponding status effect icons over the pillar name at the top center of the screen, and read the description there.

Comment: @jw013 Wow, I had no idea that's how you could read enemy effect icons (I'd always wondered if it was possible). I'll give this a try next time I'm playing!

Comment: I thought it would be easy to find a list of status effects, but all I can find is burn/shock/freeze/poison. No other references. May be worth posting this question on the official forums, too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to some people responding to [a post I made](http://forums.runicgames.com/viewtopic.php?f=30&t=53713) on the official Runic Games forum, this icon apparently indicates "fear" or "flee." This makes sense, seeing as most of the enemies I've seen this on have run away from me when this icon is present.

Digging deeper, I found that the weapon I was using ([Tormentor](http://torchlight2armory.com/item?i=-4795085444634177191)), has a 10% chance to cast [Fire Storm](http://torchlight2armory.com/skill?i=WC_FireStorm) from the target, which itself has a 67% chance of casting *Target flees for 5 seconds*. This essentially yields a 6.7% chance of this effect occurring, which is why I was seeing it so infrequently.